# Планировщик заданий Андроид

Tags: android, service, служба

Я пишу что-то типа ежедневника, в который пользователь записывает задачи на определенную дату и время. Мне нужно осуществить напоминание пользователю о задаче. Как я могу это реализовать? Все задачи находятся в базе, сортировка по дате и времени.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запланировать выполнение какого-либо кода можно при помощи [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) и [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

По алгоритму: при добавлении новой задачи (или удалении старой) добавляете ее в расписание 
AlarmManager, который в нужный момент вызовет код, описанный в вашем `BroadcastReceiver` (см. пример)

Comment: Спасибо! А если устройство перезагрузить? Написано, что сигнализация отменяется каждый раз, когда устройство перезагружается

Comment: @Ingvar надо создать BroadcaseReceiver BOOT_COMPLETE ([тык][1])

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android